# How to access a local directory instead of URL of OSM server?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am playing with the Leaflet.html demo provided on their website to try and build a offline map application.

I am trying to change the following line of code

```
      // add the OpenStreetMap tiles
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19
      }).addTo(map);
```

to something like

```
      // add the OpenStreetMap tiles
      L.tileLayer('file:///downloaded-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19
      }).addTo(map);
```

where in my downloaded-tiles folder, I have all the downloaded tiles necessary for the region of interest , downloaded using this golang app [wms-tiles-downloader](https://github.com/Luqqk/wms-tiles-downloader). The application works just fine using the website url, but nothing loads or happens with the directory method.

If it looks like I am doing stuff right, could there be an issue with the tiles that I have downloaded? Or maybe a misunderstanding of the `L.tilelayer()` function?

Comment: You're using an absolute URL where you wanted to use a relative one. Do read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thanks for that. unfortunately no luck, so it must be something wrong with my files or something tile-related. Just to be clear, because it is a relative path, i should be able to use `L.tileLayer('downloaded-tiles/{z}/{x}{y}.png')`, as the downloaded-tiles folder is in the same folder "leaflet.html" is being run?

Comment: Yes. Look for errors in your browser's console, consider editing your question to include information about the directory structure of your tiles.